# Flutter - Event / timeline appointment booking layout problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter newbies here,

We are trying to create a simple appointment booking app to use in our clinic and would be grateful for some advice on how to go about doing this. I have included a mockup of what we are trying to achieve [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqxrf.png).

We require multiple columns - one for each doctor working and a timeline displaying hours fixed to the left-hand side. Appointments range from 10 minutes to 1 hour and we need to be able to select them for editing purposes. In addition to this, being able to select a cell (ie: double-click to add new appointment) is a feature we would like to implement. Also, appointments in the same column cannot overlap.

We have looked at the following:
- Flutter table layouts
- Individual columns with cards (aligned relative to the time of booking) 
- Custom painter
- Grid layouts

We have downloaded some packages such as the SyncFusion calendar and timeline app and picked them apart. However, before we go down a rabbit-hole, any advice would be amazing.

Thanks for your time

Comment: what library did you end up going with finally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_week_view 
code snippet

```
    return WeekView(
      dates: [date.subtract(const Duration(days: 1)), date, date.add(const Duration(days: 1))],
      events: [
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 1',
          description: 'A description 1',
          start: date.subtract(const Duration(hours: 1)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 18, minutes: 30)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 2',
          description: 'A description 2',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 19)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 22)),
        ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as launcher;
import 'package:flutter_week_view/flutter_week_view.dart';

/// First plugin test method.
void main() => runApp(_FlutterWeekViewDemoApp());

/// The demo material app.
class _FlutterWeekViewDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Week View Demo',
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => inScaffold(body: _FlutterWeekViewDemoAppBody()),
          '/day-view': (context) => inScaffold(
                title: 'Demo day view',
                body: _DemoDayView(),
              ),
          '/week-view': (context) => inScaffold(
                title: 'Demo week view',
                body: _DemoWeekView(),
              ),
        },
      );

  static Widget inScaffold({
    String title = 'Flutter Week View',
    @required Widget body,
  }) =>
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: body,
      );
}

/// The demo app body widget.
class _FlutterWeekViewDemoAppBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String github = 'https://github.com/Skyost/FlutterWeekView';
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
              child: Text(
                'Flutter Week View demo',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Demo day view'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/day-view'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Demo week view'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/week-view'),
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: SizedBox.expand(),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                if (await launcher.canLaunch(github)) {
                  await launcher.launch(github);
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                github,
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  color: Colors.blue[800],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The demo day view widget.
class _DemoDayView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime date = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
    return DayView(
      date: now,
      events: [
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 1',
          description: 'A description 1',
          start: date.subtract(const Duration(hours: 1)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 18, minutes: 30)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 2',
          description: 'A description 2',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 19)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 22)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 3',
          description: 'A description 3',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 23, minutes: 30)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 25, minutes: 30)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 4',
          description: 'A description 4',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 20)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 21)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 5',
          description: 'A description 5',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 20)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 21)),
        ),
      ],
      currentTimeCircleColor: Colors.pink,
    );
  }
}

/// The demo week view widget.
class _DemoWeekView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime date = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
    return WeekView(
      dates: [date.subtract(const Duration(days: 1)), date, date.add(const Duration(days: 1))],
      events: [
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 1',
          description: 'A description 1',
          start: date.subtract(const Duration(hours: 1)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 18, minutes: 30)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 2',
          description: 'A description 2',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 19)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 22)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 3',
          description: 'A description 3',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 23, minutes: 30)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 25, minutes: 30)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 4',
          description: 'A description 4',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 20)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 21)),
        ),
        FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: 'An event 5',
          description: 'A description 5',
          start: date.add(const Duration(hours: 20)),
          end: date.add(const Duration(hours: 21)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, amazing, thank you very much, we hadn’t found this one! That’s exactly what we’re looking for :)

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps, thanks.